# Qt6 build error from source. Multi-config build is only supported by Xcode, Ninja Multi-Config and Visual Studio generators

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw, qt6

I'm trying to build Qt6.3.0 from sources.
I'm new in qt and trying to build static version.
I'm use this tree:
C:/Qt/6.3.0/Src
C:/Qt/6.3.0/static

In C:/Qt/6.3.0/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf:
I add this in end of file:

```
# Static
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static -static-libgcc
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -Os -momit-leaf-frame-pointer
DEFINES += QT_STATIC_BUILD
CONFIG += static
# Static
```

In C:/Qt/6.3.0/static/make.bat:

```
set QtDir=C:/Qt/6.3.0/static
set MingwDir=C:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64
set QtSrcDir=C:/Qt/6.3.0/Src
set CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=%MingwDir%/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
:: Set a clean path including MinGW.
set PATH=%PATH%;%MingwDir%/bin;%MingwDir%/opt/bin
:: Force English locale to avoid weird effects of tools localization.
set LANG=en
:: Set environment variable QT_INSTALL_PREFIX. Documentation says it should be
:: used by configure as prefix but this does not seem to work. So, we will
:: also specify -prefix option in configure.
set QT_INSTALL_PREFIX=%QtDir%
:: Configure, compile and install Qt.
cmd /c "%QtSrcDir%/configure.bat -static -debug-and-release -platform win32-g++ -prefix %QtDir% -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -qt-sqlite -no-openssl -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests" > log_cmd.txt
mingw32-make -k -j6 > log_make.txt
mingw32-make -k -j6 install > log_make_install.txt
pause
```

But this give me this error:

```
CMake Warning at C:/Qt/6.3.0/Src/qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:264 (message):
  '-nomake tools' is not implemented yet.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Qt/6.3.0/Src/qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:790 (qtConfAddWarning)
  C:/Qt/6.3.0/Src/qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:849 (check_qt_build_parts)


CMake Warning at C:/Qt/6.3.0/Src/qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:264 (message):
  '-make libs' is not implemented yet.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Qt/6.3.0/Src/qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:790 (qtConfAddWarning)
  C:/Qt/6.3.0/Src/qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:850 (check_qt_build_parts)


CMake Error at C:/Qt/6.3.0/Src/qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:940 (message):
  Multi-config build is only supported by Xcode, Ninja Multi-Config and
  Visual Studio generators.  Current generator is "MinGW Makefiles".

  Note: Use '-cmake-generator <generator name>' option to specify the
  generator manually.
```

If i think right, it not support MinGW generator? What kind of generator should i use?

This my path:

```
D:\YD\Python\py\
D:\YD\Python\py\Scripts\
C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw1120_64\bin
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin
```

From qt installer(what i installed):

```
Qt/Qt6.3.0/MinGW 11.2.0 64-bit
Qt/Qt6.3.0/Sources
Qt/Qt6.3.0/Qt Shader Tools
Qt/Qt6.3.0/Additional Libraries
Qt/Qt6.3.0/Qt Debug Information Files
Developer and Designel Tools/Qt Creator 7.0.1 . . .
Developer and Designel Tools/Debuging Tools for Windows
Developer and Designel Tools/Qt Creator 7.0.1 Debug Symbols
Developer and Designel Tools/Qt Creator 7.0.1 Plugin Development
Developer and Designel Tools/MinGW 11.2.0 64-bit
```

I also have this:
Python v3.10.4
Strawberry Perl v5.32.1

My os:
Windows 10 Build 19044

I all make true or what is incorrect? What i should do to fix this error?

Comment: Makefiles don't support multi-config builds, i.e. you can't generate onemakefile and build release & debug, you have to generate one for debug and another one for release separately. But you are better off using the Ninja generator anyway. Just make sure your Ninja, and MinGW are reachable from the terminal you run it on.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to build both static and shared versions of Qt 6.3.0 using CMake with Ninja under MSYS2 shell (Cmake flag `-GNinja`), but I build them separately using a different out-of-source build folder but the same install destination (same `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=` CMake flag).

If you want to find out the details on how my build works, see https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/qt6.winlib (sorry, it's a bit messy because I leave a lot of previous attempts in there as comments).